# IIS 7.5 : URL Rewrite extension is Installed, but not shown (even after reboot)

Tags: web-services, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

In IIS version 7.5.7600.16385, I'm trying to redirect requests for `example.com/*` to `www.example.com/*`.

For example, if requests comes in like these:

```
http://example.com/ContactUS/
http://example.com/Donations/
```

I want IIS to redirect to these URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/ContactUS/
http://www.example.com/Donations/
```

So, as you can see, my goal is **not** to redirect all requests to the same static URL path. Instead, I'm trying to simply change the domain to the `www` subdomain while **keeping the URL path intact** for each redirect.

I've read articles that advise using an IIS extension called [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

However, when I try to install this extension the installer claims it is [already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw55h.png), and even after a reboot, the `URL Rewrite` feature is not shown anywhere in IIS 7.5.7600.16385.

The only thing I can think of, that may be causing me not to see the URL Rewrite extension (in IIS), is that I do recall installing `PHPManagerForIIS_V1.5.0.msi` onto this same server several years ago. Maybe `PHPManagerForIIS_V1.5.0` somehow overrides the `URL Rewrite` extension if you have it installed. I don't know.

Please advise if you know of a way I can accomplish my goal of dynamically redirecting all requests to their respective `www` canonical address, while keeping the URL path intact.

Comment: IIS 7.5 is end of life. Besides, PHP Manager 1.5 is very very old (as I created PHP Manager 2.0). To really know what happened, download the MSI package from https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite and install with MSI logging enabled.

Comment: @LexLi - Did you see [this](https://i.imgur.com/o81DIE7.png)?

Comment: Did you know what is Windows MSI engine (which is rather fragile) and how to execute MSI directly (from command line with logging enabled)? If not, spend some time on that to start your troubleshooting. WebPI is dead, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/429383/web-platform-installer-end-of-support-and-sunsetti.html but no doubt there are still people like you using it.

Comment: Ultimately, I accomplished these dynamic redirects by using `HTTP Redirect` instead of `URL Rewrite` (due to not ever being able to get the installed `URL Rewrite` extension to ever show up in IIS 7.5).

Comment: This entails creating an additional virtual web server for each site which is exclusively dedicated to having a single HTTP Redirect. Don't use the same physical folder for these new virtual web servers as the ones already in place! If you do, upon creating the HTTP redirect, on the newly created virtual web server, it will also create a redirect on the virtual web server you're redirecting to (creating a redirect loop).

Comment: So, its best to just create a new physical folder for each additional virtual web server. I don't particular like this solution, but it will work until I migrate these sites to Linux.

Comment: You can feel free to post/accept your own answer below, not using comments this way. You'd better perform a migration to Linux or newer Windows as quickly as possible, because end-of-life products can only give you security risks.